# Seeing location of friends in Google map in navigation mode

Tags: group-travel, google-maps

I can see the location of my friends without any issue in Google maps. However the moment I start navigation/driving then I don't see any of them.
This is especially required when we are driving together as a group in multiple cars to the same destination.
Since the map is in navigation mode, if I have to check my friends location, I have to exit navigation and only then I can see them, even though they are just a few kms ahead or behind me.

Is this possible in Google maps?

Its a feature that we sorely miss when driving with family in multiple cars.Its okay that in navigation mode, the POV is of the car you are driving and you don't see much of the route behind you, but you still see considerable route distance on map ahead of you on map. So, a quick glance at the map can tell you if there someone from your group driving just ahead of you.

Any other apps have this feature?

Comment: You have phones. You could text or call if you get separated...

Answer (score 3):

I do not know how to do it within one app, but if you can use two telephones you can have one on the navigation view and the other on the 'follow the others' view.
It will be easy enough to place two phones on the front windscreen or dash of a car, with two different phone holders, and if you place them just side by side or above each other they should not take much of your windscreen or view.

As you mention your mates to be asleep if not driving, you will have to get one of them to trust you with their phone or you can buy a cheap one for just this use. You can use map apps which do not need data for navigation, which is what I use in my bike, leaving the 'real phone with data' for the connection that shows the others.

Comment: +1, however one advantage of having data on your navigation phone is that it picks up traffic problems ahead.  If one car has data and reroutes around a delay, that could break the group.

Comment: We tried this on a drive this weekend with my brother traveling in 2 cars. Put up a phone running google maps centered on my blue dot to show my brother's location whenever he is close to me. 
I faced two issues, one the location update is very laggy. Often my bro's location update was 15-20 mins behind and I had to tap his icon and refresh, not safe while driving. Two, since the phone is not in navigation mode, the display will time out and sleep every 30 mins which is max allowed on that phone. There may be a solution to second issue, but the first issue is a real disappointment.